# K8s ingress with 2 domains both listening on port 80

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to replicate a [Name based virtual hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) with two docker images in one deployment. Unfortunately I am only able to get 1 running due to a port conflict:

```
2019/03/19 20:37:52 [ERR] Error starting server: listen tcp :5678: bind: address already in use
```

Is it really not possible to have two images listening on the same port as part of the same deployment? Or am I going wrong elsewhere?

Minimal example adapted from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes)

```
# set up ingress
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml

# set up load balancer
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/cloud-generic.yaml

# spin up two containers in one deployment, same container port
kubectl apply -f test.yaml
```

`test.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo2
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo2
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo12
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo12
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo12
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo1
          image: hashicorp/http-echo
          args:
            - "-text=echo1"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5678
        - name: echo2
          image: hashicorp/http-echo
          args:
            - "-text=echo2"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5678
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: echo1.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: echo1
              servicePort: 80
    - host: echo2.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: echo2
              servicePort: 80
```

Update:
If I add a separate deployment it works. Is this by design or is there any way that I can achieve this in one deployment (reason: I'd like to be able to reset all deployed domains at once)?

Comment: Have you verified that your deployments/pods backing the service is actually up and responding? The Ingress will not route to pods/services that are unhealthy.

Comment: In my prior tests the pods did show as healthy. I have changed the question content to a smaller, hopefully more easily reproducable question. It seems I can't get to deploy multiple images that have the same open port.

Comment: You should have your ports on the deployments set to map to the container host. Instead of `containerPort :5678` on both, you can try `5678:5678` for one and `5679:5678` for the other. Then in your services, your target ports would be 5678 and 5679 respectively. The ingress will map the ingress controller's port 80 -> port 80 of your echo service. Port 80 of your port service will map to your container host's 5678, then your host's 5678 will map to your container network's 5678.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed it to containerPort: 5679:5678 but the apply command then produces: error validating "test.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort.containerPort: got "string", expected "integer",

Comment: It looks like there is hostPort but that still triggers the same error: "listen tcp :5678: bind: address already in use"

Comment: Put the port mappings as number right under the `ports` attribute, instead of containerPort.

Comment: Thanks for your continued support. Much appreciated. Tried the following variations ports: 5679:5678, ports: - 5678, ports: - port: 5678 but they all didn't apply due to failed validations like "missing required field "containerPort", got "number", expected "map", got "string", expected "array"]

Comment: No worries! I'm learning too... Sorry, I got fixated on the container port mappings. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you - learned something today. Will have to find a new approach as I had hoped I could deploy a set of websites all at once in one helm release (which maps to a deployment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**: Creating two different service backends in one pod of one deployment. This is not what the pods are designed for. If you want to expose multiple services, you should have a pod (at least) to back each service. Deployments wrap around the pod by allowing you to define replication and liveliness options. In your case, you should have one deployment (which creates one or multiple pods that will respond to one echo request) for its corresponding service.

**Problem 2**: You are not linking your services to your backends properly. The service clearly is trying to select a label `app=echo` or `app=echo2`. In your deployment, your `app=echo12`. Consequently, the service simply won't be able to find any active endpoints.

To address the above problems, try this below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo2
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo2
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo1
          image: hashicorp/http-echo
          args:
            - "-text=echo1"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5678
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo2
          image: hashicorp/http-echo
          args:
            - "-text=echo2"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5678
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: echo1.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: echo1
              servicePort: 80
    - host: echo2.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: echo2
              servicePort: 80
```

I have tested the above in my own cluster and verified that it is working (with different ingress urls of course). Hope this helps!